# How to change AM TO PM in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to change my output to 12/30/1999 11:59:59:PM

here is my code:

```
strOutTime = datetime(1999,12,30,11,59,59)
strOutTime = strOutTime.strftime("%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S:%p")
```

But I get 12/30/1999 11:59:59:AM.
Any suggestion?

Comment: Instead of 11 use 23 for the hour.

Comment: Why would you show the wrong time? 11:59 PM would be `datetime(1999,12,30,23,59,59)`

Answer (score 1):

If you use `23` instead of `11`, you will get PM. Python is taking `11` as 11th hour of the day.

```py
strOutTime = datetime(1999,12,30,23,59,58)
strOutTime = strOutTime.strftime("%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S:%p")
```